# Select comparing dates and bookings in DB

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a `items` table and a `bookings` table.
The `bookings` has a entry/row for each day a item is booked.

I need to check wich items are not booked in a specific date interval.

I am trying to get it with MySQL and I tried

```
SELECT * FROM items AS i
LEFT JOIN day_bookings AS db ON i.id = db.id_item 
WHERE i.state <> 0
AND db.the_date NOT BETWEEN DATE('2016-02-01') AND DATE('2016-04-10')
GROUP BY i.id;
```

This gives me all items, without matching properly the dates as I would expect.

I could do this in server side code, something like:

> Select all `db.the_date` between the dates => loop all rows in result and filter away the matches.

But I would like to get it in MySQL. Any suggestions on how the query could be?

Comment: Select all the items that are booked between the dates first, then stick that into a `NOT IN` subquery

Comment: So items aren't booked for more than 1 day?

Comment: @Strawberry yes they are. In the day_bookings table there is one row per day the item is not available.

Comment: That sounds like an odd design. You'd typically just store the start and end dates of the booking.

Comment: @Strawberry good point. I just got this project with the DB already with data, andd didn't ask my self that question. But now, when you mention it, it makes me think you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all the items that are booked between the dates first, then stick that into a NOT IN subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE id_item NOT IN 
    (SELECT id_item FROM day_bookings 
     WHERE the_date BETWEEN DATE('2016-02-01') AND DATE('2016-04-10'))
```

Depending on the size of the tables, having `SELECT DISTINCT` in the nested query might, or might not, speed up the execution.

Comment: Got a error first in `WHERE id_item NOT`, then changed to `WHERE id_item NOT IN` and it worked great. Thank you for taking a look at this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for a `NULL` value in `db` where `the_date` *is* in that range - if the item doesn't exist on the right hand side of a left join, it's columns will all be `NULL`.

You also need to move the date check into the join condition, not the the WHERE clause to make this work.

```
SELECT * FROM items AS i
-- get bookings for the item between the required dates
LEFT JOIN day_bookings AS db ON i.id = db.id_item
    AND db.the_date BETWEEN DATE('2016-02-01') AND DATE('2016-04-10')
WHERE i.state <> 0
    AND db.id_item IS NULL -- only include if the booking does NOT exist
```

Comment: There are no aggregating functions here.